# Ошибка на форме WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот сообщение ошибки, не понимаю от чего? Но программа работает правильно.

> Сообщение 1   Класс FindGroup можно сконструировать, но это не первый
>   класс в файле.  В Visual Studio конструктор должен использовать первый
>   класс в файле.  Переместите код класса, чтобы он был первым в файле, и
>   еще раз попробуйте загрузить конструктор.

Как решить эту проблему?
Это скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете скриншот ошибки тоже добавить?

Comment: @Grundy уже добавлен

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код из файла _FindGroup.cs_ и _FindGroup.Designer.cs_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае, видимо, в класс формы Вы добавили еще класс. Просто перенесите все классы, кроме класса формы в отдельные файлы. А вообще, не помешало бы в таких случаях давать код, в котором ошибка, так будет проще и быстрее определить Вашу проблему.